# "Bad notification for startForeground" error when using android-upload-service

Tags: android

I don't know why I'm getting this error because I haven't actually used any notifications channels in my app and I don't intend to do.
Can somebody help me fix this?

Error:

```
2019-12-10 16:58:03.151 9542-9542/com.example.demoproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.demoproject, PID: 9542
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: null
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1894)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Activity:

```
public class File_upload extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button SelectButton, UploadButton;
    EditText PdfNameEditText ;

    Uri uri;
    String username;
    public static final String PDF_UPLOAD_HTTP_URL = "https://depcollproj.000webhostapp.com/FileUpload.php";

    public int PDF_REQ_CODE = 1;

    String PdfNameHolder, PdfPathHolder, PdfID;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeacherView.class);
        setIntent.putExtra("username",username);
        startActivity(setIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_upload);
        AllowRunTimePermission();
        Intent i=getIntent();
        username=i.getStringExtra("username");
        SelectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        UploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        PdfNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        SelectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // PDF selection code start from here .
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PDF_REQ_CODE);
            }
        });

        UploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    PdfUploadFunction();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PDF_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            SelectButton.setText("PDF is Selected");
        }
    }

    public void PdfUploadFunction() {
        PdfNameHolder = PdfNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
        if (PdfPathHolder == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please move your PDF file to internal storage & try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                PdfID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                new MultipartUploadRequest(this, PdfID, PDF_UPLOAD_HTTP_URL)
                        .addFileToUpload(PdfPathHolder, "pdf")
                        .addParameter("name", PdfNameHolder)
                        //.addParameter("username",username)
                        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                        .setMaxRetries(5)
                        .startUpload();
                Toast.makeText(this, " Upload Successful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Upload Procedure", "PdfUploadFunction:  -------"+PdfNameHolder+username);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.d("Upload Procedure", "PdfUploadFunction: Fail");
                Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    public void AllowRunTimePermission(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(File_upload.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(File_upload.this,"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission Access Dialog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(File_upload.this,new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] Result) {
        switch (RC) {
            case 1:
                if (Result.length > 0 && Result[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(File_upload.this,"Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(File_upload.this,"Permission Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just going by the error you have created some annotations which are defined with default access specifiers try making it public.
or post some code.

Comment: Can u be more specific for post some code?

Comment: It seems you are starting a foreground service (which displays a notification while running). However, you didn't set any channel for that notification. Do you start any service in you app? Could you please share how you start your service?

Comment: I meant, share the code where you use "startForeground()"

Comment: @W0rmH0le well i haven't used it anywhere in my code.I just edited my post can u go trhough it and try finding the problem??

Comment: check your `UploadNotificationConfig()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try the answer below

Try to update this:

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, PdfID, PDF_UPLOAD_HTTP_URL)
    .addFileToUpload(PdfPathHolder, "pdf")
    .addParameter("name", PdfNameHolder)
    //.addParameter("username",username)
    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
    .setMaxRetries(5)
    .startUpload();
```

To this:

```
MultipartUploadRequest uploadRequest = new MultipartUploadRequest(this, PdfID, PDF_UPLOAD_HTTP_URL)
    .addFileToUpload(PdfPathHolder, "pdf")
    .addParameter("name", PdfNameHolder)
    //.addParameter("username",username)
    .setMaxRetries(5);

// For Android > 8, we need to set an Channel to the UploadNotificationConfig.
// So, here, we create the channel and set it to the MultipartUploadRequest
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Upload", "Upload service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    UploadNotificationConfig notificationConfig = new UploadNotificationConfig();
    notificationConfig.setNotificationChannelId("Upload")

    uploadRequest.setNotificationConfig(notificationConfig)
} else {
    // If android < Oreo, just set a simple notification (or remove if you don't wanna any notification
    // Notification is mandatory for Android > 8
    uploadRequest.setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
}

uploadRequest.startUpload();
```

**Reason**

Issue is happening because that Upload library you have starts a service. On Android 8, foreground services need a notification and those notifications need a channel. When you use `setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())`, you are setting the notification but you are not adding setting any channel leading the crash you are observing.

So, in order to fix, you must create UploadNotificationConfig, set a notification channel then, you can set it to the upload request. Start the upload only after that.

**EDIT**

The channel ID logic was added on version 3.4 of that library. So, you must update your build.gradle to use the version 3.4 at least.

```
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4'
```

Comment: The class UploadNotifcationConfig doesn't have a function named setNotificationConfig

Comment: Which version of android-upload-service are you using? You can see the version in your build.gradle

Comment: i used gotev upload service:2.1

Comment: 2.1 service is too old (4 years ago). It was built for target 23 (Android M). You should migrate to a newer version. Try to use version 3.4 since it supports Android Oreo but does not support Android X yet. After updating to version Android 3.4, sync the project and you will be able to find setNotificationChannelId in class UploadNotificationConfig. If you migrate to latest version, I'm afraid you may face new issues with Android X... So, try the version 3.4

Comment: Well it seems that the user had added a IllegalException.. so everytime i get an error       "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hey dude, please set the namespace for your app by following the setup instructions: https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Setup
        at net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService.onStartCommand(UploadService.java:248)"

Comment: and if i sync up to 4 it changes the whole thing ..soo gotta redo every function

Comment: Fixed it ... Thanks a lot brother... really appreciate it  <3